# base_url() link CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, base-url

I have a problem with `base_url`

I do not understand why when I put `<? php echo base_url ()?> asset / css / style.css`

I can not reach my destination.

The link is correct in fact if I write the same in the browser I get to the css file.
in practice from what I understand the result 
I get is: localhost / site / localhost / asset / css / style.css

how can i get:

```
localhost / site /assets / css / style.css
```

using `base_url ();`

Comment: Show us the code!...

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
</head>
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'html');
```

Comment: `<?php base_url(); ?>` or `<?php echo base_url(); ?>`?

Comment: I think the problem is about the localhost / site / localhost / site / assets / css / style.css

Comment: Is this is your Question or answer?

Comment: It is a question

Comment: Then edit your question. Don't add in your question into answer tab... check here how to edit your own question https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Answer (score 0):

In `config.php` file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/website/';
$config['index_page'] = '';

# If you have online website
# $config['base_url'] = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
```

In `.htaccess` (outside application folder) - To remove `index.php` from URL

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|image|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

To access URL

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>contoller_Name/method_Name"> click here</a>
```

To access images

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/images.jpeg”>
```

To access js and css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css">
```